# Using Static methods without the Class descriptor

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to implement Task Queues in GAE.  The documentation shows:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(withUrl("/worker").param("key", key));
```

But I need to add `Builder.withUrl...` to get it to compile.

Is this an error in the documentation or is there a way to use static methods without declaring the Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`import static`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to use a static method "without the class as a prefix".